# Detecting environment in GCloud Functions (Live/Emulator)

Tags: node.js, development-environment, gcloud, serverless-framework

GCloud Functions are great and the emulator is a cool tool, but I'm having problems figuring out a way to detect wether I am running in a `live` mode or in the `emulator`.

`Environment variables` would come to mind, but I can't find a way to pass them along to the function when calling.

`Runtime config` might also be a solution but the emulator does not support this.

Easy fix would be using a param in the payload e.g. `isDev: true` and then check in the function:

```
  if (data.isDev === true) 
  { //use dev config } 
  else 
  { // use live config }
```

but I'd keep that as a last resort solution.

Any other ideas on what could be a better solution?